# Maximum data storage in a paper sheet? which theory should I look for?

Tags: soft-question

I'd love to study a problem:
How much information can be stored in a blank paper sheet.

with those considerations:
"store in a sheet" means writte letters or numbers or equations, with a pen and a human hand.

"writte" means there should be a good size of letter to be legible by a person without lens.

also try that the information is not redundant or out of context or incoherent.

Which area of math can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could view the sheet as information channel and determine the [Shannon Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of the information written on the sheet.

Assuming an `A4` sheet with 213 x 296 mm², you could draw 252192 dots 1x1 mm² on the sheet. If each presence or absence of a dot represents one bit, the information content of the sheet would be some 31 kByte.

This can be increased, if you allow smaller dots.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not sure why I'm downvoted, I'd wish soemone clarify their intentions at least :/.

Comment: I guess that the downvoters objected a lack of clarity in your question. You don't explain any own thoughts and solution attempts. Please consider accepting the answer if it is helpful for you.